# Journey Builder - sending email on a specific day of the week?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way to send an email on a specific day of the week in Journey Builder? I know there are the options "wait x days until 2pm", but I would like to send an email out on the 2nd Monday after signup without having to resort to queries and automations.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this using the Journey Builder UI. We've built a [Custom Activity](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/extend/creating-activities.html) for Journey Builder which does exactly that, but that's a lot more effort than creating queries and automations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I eventually found a workaround using automations.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to create a "Helper Automation" consisting of a query activity which retrieves the "Day" value of the date field and puts that in another field in the Data Extension.  Then I had the Journey wait a few hours until this hourly query had run.  Next was using a conditional filter to see what day the new field value is (Monday, Tuesday, Saturday etc.), and wait an appropriate amount of days (wait 1 day, 4 days, 7 days) before starting the next steps.

Comment: Did this work for you?