# Email should not go on Weekend through journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have got a scenario where we need to restrict email sending on weekend through Journey Builder.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: I think your request is overly broad. Please tell us what kinds of journeys you have and why avoiding weekend emails is necessary. Should emails be skipped or do they need to be held until the weekday?

Comment: this is required. emails needs to be held until the next weekday. that means emails will be sent on monday.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this would be to create a separate Data Extension linked to the Journey where you append current Date and a flag for "Sent/Not Sent" in Update Contact to the Separate Data Extension.

Then put up a Automation that uses SQL to figure out if today is a weekday or weekend and send, you also need to check for those that have are Today - 2 days/ and Not Sent, they are the ones that have been inserted Sat/Sun and will not be included in the 1st send, this would probably be a second query.

I don't know if DATEPART from T-SQL is supported in Marketing Cloud, otherwise you could use the CASE formula below.

You can also mark these as "Sent" in a second Query when you also send the emails for future reliability.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gk3BAAQ

This questions seems related to this one when i searched for "marketing cloud journey prevent being sent on weekend".

[Journey Builder - sending email on a specific day of the week?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140672/journey-builder-sending-email-on-a-specific-day-of-the-week)