# Is there a way to specify Journey Builder Email Sends to occur only during a designated timeframe (i.e. Business Hours)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, send-email

Similar to the Send-Throttling "Delivery Window" setting, is there some way to achieve only sending emails during a specific timeframe throughout the day when an Email Activity is used in Journey Builder?

The use case is that emails would be sent out as a part of a journey and include a Call-to-Action that encourages the recipient to call a contact center. In order to avoid a large amount of calls occurring at once (if all contacts are evaluated for the Email Send at the same time), is there a way to throttle those sends across a designated time frame?

I don't think that any of the wait activities have functionality that would achieve that functionality, nor do I know of additional Journey Builder settings that accomplish it.

Is this something that could be potentially achieved with a Custom Journey Builder Canvas Activity, or are there any additional ways that we could achieve this functionality?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237600/email-should-not-go-on-weekend-through-journey-builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Journey Build Email activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_configure_the_send_email_activity.htm&type=5) has an area where you can set the throttle/delivery window

> Send Throttling - Select and set a delivery window and hourly threshold to set a maximum quantity of emails that can be sent each hour.

You can also possible use a [wait by attribute activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_wait_for_a_date_based_on_an_attribute_value.htm&type=5), and in the entry source DE provide a date/time for each record to control when they subscriber leaves the wait step

Comment: This looks like the right approach. It would appear that the "Send Throttling" section of the Journey Builder Email Activity is not activated by default on the backend by Salesforce Professional Services. I've opened a ticket to see why that's not visible during our canvas activity configuration.